# jquery make synchronous call and execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code the api `execute_wc` is called which in turn calls a recursive function `poll_results` and returns only when there is a status != 1. Now when the function `poll_results` is called it is asynchronous so the `if else` condition in `submit_stat` is not executed.how to handle this condition

```
function submit_stat(){
    var poll_status = '';
    $.post("/reports/execute_wc/", snddata,
    function callbackHandler(data, textstatus)
    {
        console.log('got response');
        if (data.status == 0)
        {
            poll_status  = poll_results();
            if (poll_status == 1){

            }
            else if(poll_status == 0)
            {
                alert('Error while processing data.Please check input files');
            }
        }
        else if (data.status == 1)
        {
                alert('Error while processing data');
        }
     },
     "json"
     );
}

function poll_results(){
  $.post('/reports/poll_wcstatus/', function(data) {
    if(data.wce_status == 1){
        return setTimeout(poll_results,5000);
    }
    else if (data.wce_status != 1 || data.wce_status != 3)  
    {
        alert('return 1');
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('return 0');
        return 0;
    }
   });
 }
```

Edit 1:

```
function poll_results(callback){
  var callback='';
  $.post('/reports/poll_wcstatus/', function(data) {
    //alert(data);  // process results here
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.wce_status);
    if(data.wce_status == 1){
        return setTimeout(poll_results,5000);
    }
    else if (data.wce_status != 1 || data.wce_status != 3){
        alert('return 1');
        //return 1;
        callback(1);
    }
    else //3 is fatal error shoul
    {
        alert('return 0');
        callback(0);
        //return 0;
    }
});
}



 $.post("/reports/execute_wc/", snddata,
    function callbackHandler(data, textstatus)
    {
        console.log('got response');
        if (data.status == 0)
        {
            alert('starting script');
            //poll_status  = poll_results();
            poll_results(function(poll_status){
                if (poll_status == 1){
                    alert('Content extratcted.Please download the results file');
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#downloadfile').show();
                    $('#downloadfile').html('').append('<a href="'+ data.url +'">Download output</a>');
                }
                else if(poll_status == 0)
                {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    alert('Error while processing data.Please check input files');
                }
            });
        }
        else if (data.status == 1)
        {
            $('#loading').hide();
            alert('Error while processing data');
        }
     },
     "json"
     );
```

Comment: You can use a callback when `poll_results` is being called.

Comment: Can u give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Callback function**. Example below

```
function submit_stat(){
    var poll_status = '';
    $.post("/reports/execute_wc/", snddata,
    function callbackHandler(data, textstatus)
    {
        console.log('got response');
        if (data.status == 0)
        {
           poll_results(function(poll_status){  //pass a function definition as a parameter to your another function, this is called callback function
             if (poll_status == 1){

             }
             else if(poll_status == 0)
             {
                alert('Error while processing data.Please check input files');
             }
           });

        }
        else if (data.status == 1)
        {
                alert('Error while processing data');
        }
     },
     "json"
     );
}

function poll_results(callback){   //here callback variable holds a function within it
  $.post('/reports/poll_wcestatus/', function(data) {
    if(data.wce_status == 1){
        return setTimeout(poll_results,5000);
    }
    else if (data.wce_status != 1 || data.wce_status != 3)  
    {
        alert('return 1');
        callback(1);  //execute the callback function
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('return 0');
        callback(0);  //execute the callback function
    } 
   });
 }
```

Comment: @Rajeev I did give the solution.. See the comments in the code.. I pointed out the changes

Comment: Hi get an error as (index):219 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: sure you have made all the necessary changes??

Comment: Can you paste it in some Fiddle and share the link?

Comment: @Rajeev can you check by assigning the `callback` variable to another variable before your ajax call and then using this new variable to execute the callback function?

Comment: Pls see edit 1 again ,is this what youare saying( var callback=''; ) ? Still giving an error

Comment: @Rajeev do this ` var NewCallback = callback;` and then use this while executing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112179/discussion-between-rajeev-and-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive data asynchronously, you will need to utilize callbacks. Add a function to `poll_results` and data will be passed to when the asynchronous call has been done.

```
function submit_stat(){
    var poll_status = '';
    $.post("/reports/execute_wc/", snddata,
    function callbackHandler(data, textstatus)
    {
        console.log('got response');
        if (data.status == 0)
        {
            poll_results(function(poll_status)
            {
                if (poll_status == 1){

                }
                else if(poll_status == 0)
                {
                    alert('Error while processing data.Please check input files');
                }
            });
        }
        else if (data.status == 1)
        {
                alert('Error while processing data');
        }
     },
     "json"
     );
}

function poll_results(callback){
  $.post('/reports/poll_wcstatus/', function(data) {
    if(data.wce_status == 1){
        return setTimeout(poll_results,5000);
    }
    else if (data.wce_status != 1 || data.wce_status != 3)  
    {
        callback(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        callback(0);
    }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Maybe time travel does actually exist.

Comment: I get an error as (index):219 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function